# Call javascript functions when Partial view is rendered

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, model-view-controller

I am rendering a partial view `CREATE` as popup when create button is clicked.

This means dynamically a div is appended to main view on button click.

After this div is generated and all elements inside this are loaded, after that I want to call javascript functions.

All the answers I am able to find are using `.load()` event, but my scenario is different.  I am not loading partial view div using `("#div").load(URL, function(){});` my div is generated dynamically

Please suggest some help

Comment: What do you mean by "generated dynamically" ? Do you create the div in JS and then append it to the body of the page ?

Comment: Just defer the code you want to run after appending / inserting the div. It'll give the DOM the time to make the div available for other code. This assumes the code you want to run affects the div.

Answer (score 2):

JavaScript is executed synchronously.  If you are building "the view" using jQuery and then inserting it into the DOM, then just execute your "post render" code after the markup is inserted into the DOM.

```
$('#myContainer').append(someMarkup);
execSomePostRenderFunction();
```

If you are using ajax to load the partial view/html content from the server then you would use the `load()` function and put your post render code in the callback.

```
$('#myContainer').load('route/to/Partial', execSomePostRenderFunction);
```

or you can use an anonymous function:

```
$('#myContainer').load('route/to/Partial', function(){
    //...do something here
});
```

Your question is a little confusing because you have the question tagged ajax but say you are not loading the partial view.  You also might want to specify which MVC framework your are using so someone can give you more targeted guidance.

Partial Views in ASP.NET MVC, for example, are a completely server-side technology and the only way to render a partial view after page has loaded (like on a button click event) is through ajax and the `load()` function (you could also use `$.get()` or `$.ajax()` but `load()` is easier; that's why it was created).